# How to add IF ELSE by referencing to previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to read my previous value of "OPENSEATING" and store it into the variable @OPENSEATING. For the second query I want it to check first the value of @OPENSEATING if match condition do the below query.
i believe my declaration is correct, is there any syntax error?

```
DECLARE @OPENSEATING AS BIT
    SELECT

        '2019-01-31' AS DATE,


    (SELECT 
      THEATRES.OPENSEATING
        FROM
            SEAT LEFT JOIN THEATRES ON SEAT.ROOMID = THEATRES.ID
            LEFT JOIN SHOWTIMES AS B  ON THEATRES.ID = B.THEATREID 
            LEFT JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO = SEAT.SEATNO AND B.ID = TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID
        WHERE
            B.ID = A.ID
        GROUP BY THEATRES.OPENSEATING) AS @OPENSEATING,


    IF(@OPENSEATING =0)
    BEGIN
      (SELECT 
        (THEATRES.CAPACITY - COUNT(TICKET_ITEMS.ID)) AS SEATREMAINING

      FROM
        SEAT LEFT JOIN THEATRES ON SEAT.ROOMID = THEATRES.ID
        LEFT JOIN SHOWTIMES  ON THEATRES.ID = SHOWTIMES.THEATREID 
        LEFT JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO = SEAT.SEATNO AND SHOWTIMES.ID = TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID
      WHERE
        SHOWTIMES.ID = A.ID
      GROUP BY THEATRES.CAPACITY) AS REMAININGSEAT
    END
    ELSE IF(@OPENSEATING =1)
    BEGIN
      (SELECT 
        (THEATRES.CAPACITY - COUNT(TICKET_ITEMS.ID)) AS SEATREMAINING

      FROM
        SHOWTIMES LEFT JOIN THEATRES ON THEATRES.ID = SHOWTIMES.THEATREID 
        LEFT JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO = SEAT.SEATNO AND SHOWTIMES.ID = TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID
      WHERE
        SHOWTIMES.ID = A.ID
      GROUP BY THEATRES.CAPACITY) AS REMAININGSEAT
    END



        SHOWSCHEDULES.ID AS SHOWSCHEDULE_ID,
        A.ID AS SHOWTIME_ID,
        A.THEATREID
    FROM
        SHOWSCHEDULES JOIN SHOWTIMES AS A ON SHOWSCHEDULES.ID = A.SHOWSCHEDULEID
        JOIN SHOWLANGUAGES ON A.SHOWLANGUAGEID = SHOWLANGUAGES.ID
    WHERE
        '2019-01-31' BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SHOWSCHEDULES.SHOWFROMDATE, 20) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SHOWSCHEDULES.SHOWTODATE, 20)
     AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 8) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.SHOWENDTIME,8) 
  ORDER BY SHOWBEGINTIME_24 ASC
    ;
```

AS SUGGESTED BY @Slava Murygin I tried creating CTE TABLE as below but even this is showing error, what is wrong with my simple cte table. **The inner query is working fine**.

```
WITH cte_name (OPENSEATING) AS (
    SELECT

        (SELECT 
      THEATRES.OPENSEATING
        FROM
            SEAT LEFT JOIN THEATRES ON SEAT.ROOMID = THEATRES.ID
            LEFT JOIN SHOWTIMES AS B  ON THEATRES.ID = B.THEATREID 
            LEFT JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO = SEAT.SEATNO AND B.ID = TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID
        WHERE
            B.ID = A.ID
        GROUP BY THEATRES.OPENSEATING) AS OPENSEATING

  FROM
        SHOWSCHEDULES JOIN SHOWTIMES AS A ON SHOWSCHEDULES.ID = A.SHOWSCHEDULEID
        JOIN SHOWLANGUAGES ON A.SHOWLANGUAGEID = SHOWLANGUAGES.ID
    WHERE
        '2019-01-31' BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SHOWSCHEDULES.SHOWFROMDATE, 20) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SHOWSCHEDULES.SHOWTODATE, 20)
     AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 8) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.SHOWENDTIME,8)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in one query. You have to get variable in the first query and then use it in IF statement.

If you WANT to use ONLY ONE statement then you have to use CTEs, but it will hide the logic and will be hard to debug.

It might be something like this, but no guarantee it will work, because I have no idea about your business logic and data behind:

```
;WITH OPENSEATING as (
    SELECT THEATRES.OPENSEATING, B.ID
    FROM SEAT 
    LEFT JOIN THEATRES ON SEAT.ROOMID = THEATRES.ID
    LEFT JOIN SHOWTIMES AS B  ON THEATRES.ID = B.THEATREID 
    LEFT JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO = SEAT.SEATNO AND B.ID = TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID
    GROUP BY THEATRES.OPENSEATING),
REMAININGSEAT0 as (
    SELECT st.ID, (t.CAPACITY - COUNT(ti.ID)) AS SEATREMAINING
    FROM SEAT as s 
    LEFT JOIN THEATRES as t ON s.ROOMID = t.ID
    LEFT JOIN SHOWTIMES as st ON t.ID = st.THEATREID 
    LEFT JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON ti.SEATNO = s.SEATNO AND st.ID = ti.SHOWTIMESID
    GROUP BY t.CAPACITY),
REMAININGSEAT1 as (
    SELECT st.ID, (t.CAPACITY - COUNT(ti.ID)) AS SEATREMAINING
    FROM SHOWTIMES as st
    LEFT JOIN THEATRES as t ON t.ID = st.THEATREID 
    LEFT JOIN SEAT as s ON s.ROOMID = t.ID
    LEFT JOIN TICKET_ITEMS as ti ON ti.SEATNO = s.SEATNO AND st.ID = ti.SHOWTIMESID
    GROUP BY t.CAPACITY)

SELECT '2019-01-31' AS DATE
    , ss.ID AS SHOWSCHEDULE_ID
    , A.ID AS SHOWTIME_ID
    , A.THEATREID
    , SEATREMAINING = CASE OS.OPENSEATING WHEN 0 THEN RS0.SEATREMAINING ELSE RS1.SEATREMAINING END
FROM SHOWSCHEDULES as ss
INNER JOIN SHOWTIMES AS A ON ss.ID = A.SHOWSCHEDULEID
INNER JOIN SHOWLANGUAGES as SL ON A.SHOWLANGUAGEID = SL.ID
INNER JOIN OPENSEATING as OS ON OS.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN REMAININGSEAT0 as RS0 ON RS0.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN REMAININGSEAT1 as RS1 ON RS1.ID = A.ID
WHERE '2019-01-31' BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ss.SHOWFROMDATE, 20) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ss.SHOWTODATE, 20)
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 8) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.SHOWENDTIME,8) 
ORDER BY SHOWBEGINTIME_24 ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to your CTE as:

```
WITH cte_name (OPENSEATING) AS (

    SELECT 
  THEATRES.OPENSEATING as OPENSEATING
    FROM
        SEAT LEFT JOIN THEATRES ON SEAT.ROOMID = THEATRES.ID
        LEFT JOIN SHOWTIMES AS B  ON THEATRES.ID = B.THEATREID 
        LEFT JOIN TICKET_ITEMS ON TICKET_ITEMS.SEATNO = SEAT.SEATNO AND B.ID = TICKET_ITEMS.SHOWTIMESID
    WHERE
        B.ID = A.ID
    GROUP BY THEATRES.OPENSEATING
)

select openseating from
    cte_name, SHOWSCHEDULES JOIN SHOWTIMES AS A ON SHOWSCHEDULES.ID = A.SHOWSCHEDULEID
    JOIN SHOWLANGUAGES ON A.SHOWLANGUAGEID = SHOWLANGUAGES.ID
WHERE
    '2019-01-31' BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SHOWSCHEDULES.SHOWFROMDATE, 20) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SHOWSCHEDULES.SHOWTODATE, 20)
 AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 8) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.SHOWENDTIME,8)
```

Comment: error "The multi-part identifier "A.ID" could not be bound." ... i think its due to table A is executed after CTE

Comment: @KIRPALSINGH In where clause you use A.Id but you do not use any table as alias A in the CTE block. It will not work.

Comment: @AbuZafor If you look at my question above, i did include table a at SHOWTIMES AS A

Comment: yes, but that is outside the CTE block. Can you please add some sample data for each table and explain what do you want. Then I can try.